# Why does this piece of code produce following error: "user.updateUser is not a function"

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have created a general function for creating a new user with firebase. It looks like this:

```
export function createUserEmailPassword(email, password, username) {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential) => {
      const user = userCredential.user;
      user
        .updateProfile({
          displayName: username,
        })
        .then(() => {
          alert("Welcome " + user.displayName);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      const errorMessage = error.message;
      alert(errorMessage);
    });
}
```

For some reason, user.updatProfile produces the error: "user.updateProfile is not a function", which doesn't let me set the display name.

The goal of the function is to set the displayname to the username upon creating a new user.

Comment: so, is it `updateUser` or `updateProfile` - your title says one thing, your code and question say another - what is `userCredential.user`? what makes you think it has this `updateProfile` method (or `updateUser` ) - is `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` something you wrote, or is it documented somewhere?

Comment: This error means that most likely `user` is not what you think it is. If `user.updateProfile` is undefined for instance, that will cause that error.

Comment: 37.2 second search suggests `updateProfile` is not a user method, but a method you can use on a user ... so, it's `updateProfile(user, {......})` where `updateProfile` is imported from `firebase/auth"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`updateProfile()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#updateprofile) is a top-level function in new Firebase Modular SDK just like `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import { updateProfile } from "firebase/auth"

createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  .then(async (userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    await updateProfile(user, {
      displayName: username,
    })
    alert("Welcome " + user.displayName);
  })
```